# Cookie being assigned on website

Tags: cookie, privacy-policy, drupal-6

I am updating our privacy policy and was checking what cookies were being assigned to visitors from our website. I found one that I am unaware of. It is a Drupal 6 site and there is no module being used for cookies.

Here it is:

```
NAME  SESSdc9c27ea8a315c880910709856639859 
VALUE  dh82otuopssampaguospoh26a7 
DOMAIN  mydomain.ca 
PATH  / 
EXPIRES  10/3/2013 7:18:36 PM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal 6 sets a cookie to track sessions for anonymous visitors and users that log in, see:
 [Drupal 6 - session.inc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!session.inc/6)

You can view the source code and comments at the bottom of the above link as to what's being stored and read.

You could add a statement to your privacy policy regarding this, but most sites just use blanket statements to describe how they handle privacy in general terms since most users don't notice things like cookies being set.

If it's a significant concern however and you want to disable cookies for *anonymous* visitors, see this:
 [DRUPAL FOR PRIVACY BUFFS: CONFIGURING YOUR DRUPAL 6 SITE TO WORK WITHOUT COOKIES FOR ANONYMOUS](http://www.advomatic.com/blogs/marco-carbone/drupal-privacy-configuring-your-site-to-work-without-cookies-for-anonymous-users)

Note that this may impact your site's functionality for anonymous visitors, so you should test this prior to going live.